# Xcode 5 and apps deployed for previous versions of iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Maybe it´s a really stupid question, but how will my app look on previous versions of iOS if I make it with the new Xcode? It looks good in the simulator, but thats just showing ios7. I have made some design changes to fit ios7 and since the toolbars and navBars had to be moved it feels like it will look awful in ios6 for example.

Comment: you can test it by running on iOS6, whether its looking awful or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe will your app look good on older versions. But that depends on your code. You have to test it.

You can install your app on a older iOS version by setting the deployment target in the general tab.
After that, you should be able to run the app on older iOS simulator. This should look like this
[image: iOS Simulators]
If there is still only the iOS 7 simulator, than go ahead and hit more simulators to get more.

Answer (score 0):

Having installed Xcode Version 5.0.1 (5A2053), the More Simulators option is no longer present.  The Components tab on Xcode Preferences/Downloads only offers the options of 6.0 and 6.1.  The release notes don't say that anything's been removed, but I can't find how to reinstate pre-6 simulators.

[Further note] In the iOS Simulator user guide, there's a section on iOS Version Limitations that seems to imply that even 6.0 might disappear without notice - "iOS Simulator does not have complete backward compatibility.  In addition to supporting iOS 7.0, iOS Simulator supports iOS 6.1".  Worrying if you still have apps that target 5.0 or 5.1.